# Import content in nodes with media:image fields using Migrate from csv source

Tags: migrations

I try to import content from a `.csv` file into *article* nodes of a fresh D9 install using `Migrate`, `Migrate Plus`, `Migrate Tools`, `Migrate csv source` and `Migrate File (extended)`

My *article* content type has a `field_article_media_image` expecting a media image item.

When I run the migration, the *articles* are created correctly BUT the `field_article_media_image` is still empty. I see the image has been imported in the filesystem, but created as a file, not as a media item (not present in the media tab) and it is not linked to the article.

```
//import-articles.yml

id: import_articles
label: Import articles
migration_group: import_articles_group

destination:
  plugin: entity:node

source:
  constants:
    DESTINATION_PATH: 'public://migrations/articles/images/'
  plugin: 'csv'
  path: 'migrations/articles/articles.csv'
  delimiter: ';'
  enclosure: '"'
  header_offset: 0
  ids:
    - id
  fields:
    0:
      name: id
      label: 'Id'
    1:
      name: title
      label: 'Title'
    2:
      name: body
      label: 'Body'
    3:
      name: field_article_media_image
      label: 'Image'
process:
  title: title
  body/value: body
  body/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'basic_html'
  field_article_media_image:
    - plugin: image_import
      source: field_article_media_image
      destination: constants/DESTINATION_PATH
      title: title
      skip_on_error: true
    - plugin: log
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article
```

The log gives no error. Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

After what @Joseph commented, I tried this code:

```
...
    field_article_media_image:
        source: field_article_media_image
        plugin: entity_lookup
        entity_type: media
        bundle: image
        bundle_key: bundle
        value_key: 'name'
        access_check: 0
...
```

Everything is working now, I think `value_key` needed quotes, and *maybe* `access_check` had to be set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How your article is related to the image is actually like this:

```
Article (node) -> Image (media) -> File (file)
```

So there are actually *three* migrations you have to do, assuming you're not doing anything special and just doing vanilla migrations.

- The first migration will be to a `File` entity. The destination of this migration is `entity:file` which will migrate the information to the `file_managed` table. This is what migrates file metadata, like where it is in the file system, when it was changed, when it was modified, etc.
- The second migration will be to a `Media` entity. The destination of this migration is `entity:media` with bundle `image`, which will create a media entity of the file. This migration is usually 1:1 with the file it's representing. This is the entity that should be related to by other entities in the system. You do a `migrate_lookup` on the `File` migration using that file's ID.

  - *I believe this is the migration you're missing.*
- The last migration will be your `Article` migration, which is your article data from your CSV (the migration you wrote). You'll need to do a `migrate_lookup` on the media migration using the file's ID for `field_article_media_image`.

Comment: In the meantime, I managed to import the images as Media entities (using drupal/media_library_importer). Can I go directly to the last migration? The title for the Media item is a unique key I've got in my .csv

Comment: @laurent If you used tools other than Migrate API to migrate Media, your article migration cannot use the [`migration_lookup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!migrate!src!Plugin!migrate!process!MigrationLookup.php/class/MigrationLookup) plugin to link article to media. But you can create a [process plugin](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process/writing-a-process-plugin) and use that column in your CSV to find the correct media entity in the DB using [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/introduction-to-entity-api-in-drupal-8).

Comment: In Migrate Plus, the plugin `entity_lookup` seems to be doing just what I want, the example provided is _hooking_ nodes to users entities, I don't know how to transpose to media entities, but that does not sound overly complicated . I'm new to Drupal, so if I can avoid writing a plugin...

Comment: @laurent `entity_lookup` can do what I described. You just need to configure it to point to the right `entity_type` ("media"), `bundle` ("image"), `bundle_key` ("bundle"), and most importantly `value_key` - the machine name of the field in your media entity that holds the value that coincides with the value in your articles CSV.

Answer (score 0):

What I did that work:

```
  field_hero_image/target_id:
-
  plugin: migration_lookup
  migration: previous_migrate_media_image
  source: node_uid
-
  plugin: skip_on_empty
  method: row
  message: 'nid is missing'


migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - previous_migrate_user
    - previous_migrate_media_image
  optional: { }
```